# Angularjs ng-click first click not working on mobile

Tags: angularjs, mobile, angularjs-ng-click

I'm new to angularjs. Here is my code

```
 <ul>
        <li ng-if="book.account.Customer.HasWorkspaceAccess"><a href ng-click="book.setType('workspace')" class="clickable">Book a Workspace</a></li>
        <li ng-if="book.account.Customer.HasMeetingRoomAccess"><a href ng-click="book.setType('meetingroom')" class="clickable">Book a Meeting Room</a></li>
        <li ng-if="book.account.Customer.HasBoardRoomAccess"><a href ng-click="book.setType('boardroom')" class="clickable">Book a Boardroom</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/CustomerAccount">My Account</a></li>
</ul>
```

Somehow all a tags is not working for the first tap on mobile device. It's active  after tapping and second tap will trigger the ng-click function.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: ngClick is deprecated. have a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick
I think in your case you should go for ngTouch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however ng-touch is not working on desktop browser. I still need the functionality on desktop.

Comment: Also I found this issue only happens on safari. Chrome on Android device is fine.

Comment: I have a similar problem, have you found anything?